# Can someone explain what's going on here step-by-step?

Tags: java

```
public int pray(int secondsPrayed){
    int randomRecoveryValue = secondsPrayed + new Random().nextInt(3);
    int actuallyRecoveredValue = Math.min(this.MAX_MP -this.mp,randomRecoveryValue);
    this.mp += actuallyRecoveredValue;
    return actuallyRecoveredValue;
}
```

This is from a book I'm currently using to learn. The objective is to create a `pray` method for a `Priest` object that restores its MP by the amount of seconds prayed plus 0 to 2 at random. I don't quite understand two things:

1. 3 after `nextInt` rather than 2 (the book's answer) - why is this when we're trying to get 0 to 2 at random?
2. `actuallyRecoveredValue` returns its value to `secondsPrayed`; however, to me it looks like that to get `actuallyRecoveredValue` in the first place we need `RandomRecoveryValue`, which in turn needs `secondsPrayed`, which at that point doesn't seem to exist? I'm new to Java so I don't have much experience with returning values and such.

Comment: 1.) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-

Comment: 3 doesn't exist in Java's eyes it sees it as I must count 3 numbers. Java starts from 0. Counts that as the first number.

Comment: `nextInt(n)` returns a random number less than `n`. So `nextInt(3)` returns 0, 1 or 2. And I didn't understand your second question.

Comment: Why are you saying that `secondsPrayed` does not exist? It is passed as a parameter to the `pray` method, therefore it exists.

Comment: I mean secondsPrayed exists but only as a value-less box until actuallyRecoveredValue gives its value to it right? So how is it used in earlier equations? Or does the return happen before the rest of the method despite being placed at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The nextInt() method returns an integer value between zero and the parameter you used (3 in your case). While zero is included in the range, the last element of the range is not.

You can think that nextInt(n) returns n possible values, meaning the range between "0" and "n-1"

```
nextInt(5) // can return 0,1,2,3,4
```

2) The code is a little bit messy, I'll give you that, and as you said to get you have to determine the value of "randomRecoveryValue" in order to determine actuallyRecoveredValue. The method pray() does three things:

- Calculates the recovered value, based on the input param and some randomness
- Adjusts this value, so that the priest cannot heal over its full health. That happens at the third line, basically the priest heals for a number of points equal to "randomRecoveryValue" only if its current MP is not too high, otherwise he heals for the value that will get him to full health.
- Update the value of his MP
- Returns how much the he actually healed, not necessary, but may be useful to the caller of this method

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
nextInt(int n)
```

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0
>   (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this
>   random number generator's sequence.

---

You pass `secondsPrayed` as variable into the method, so it does exist inside the method ([scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/)). From the code you posted, we can't tell if `actuallyRecoveredValue returns its value to secondsPrayed` is true.

> to me it looks like that to get actuallyRecoveredValue in the first
>   place we need RandomRecoveryValue, which in turn needs secondsPrayed

it's true, but as stated above, `secondsPrayed` does exist